# Retrieve Distinct Records in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2008

I have a DataSet and Select few records from Table in DataSet using following query:

`EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> GenresQuery = from genre in Books.AsEnumerable() where genre.Field<string>("genre") == strGenresSelectionParameter select genre;`

It is working fine but, I want to select distinct records. How it can be done ?

Comment: Select what records?  There's not enough information here for us to know what it is you're talking about.  p.s., that code would not be valid, the query is of type `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, not what you have there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx)

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> GenresQuery = (from genre in Books.AsEnumerable()
                                    where genre.Field<string>("genre") == strGenresSelectionParameter 
                                    select genre).Distinct();
```

Comment: Got this error: **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>' to 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

Comment: You need to assign the result to `IEnumerable<DataRow>` not `EnumerableRowCollection`